# Dynamic TextField width based on user input

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

By default, a TextField has a bottom border underneath it. The only way to control its width is by setting the width of the TextField itself (or wrapping in a Container). However, both of these involve hardcoding the width. How do I dynamically change the width of the TextField so that the underlining bottom border is only the width of the inputted text (or the hint text)?

Here are some examples.

The first image is a TextField with hint text. Its width is equal to the screen width.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter title"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

That produces the following:
[image]

Now, I constrain the width with a Container:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 70,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter title"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

When I use a container and set its width, it will never change after that. How do I have the width dynamically change based on the length of the text input?

Comment: any update for this question?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't been able to try it until now. Using a wrap did not seem to change anything. Its width still remains the same. I updated my question to clarify possible confusion.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I updated my post with code and better screenshots 

Comment: I found https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field/example package. but I didn't check it package.

Answer (score 1):

```
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child: TextFormField(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, 
[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations.